# Eliminating NDSolve Instability

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, numerical-integration, numerics, warning-messages

```
pde = {D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], t] == -Cos[θ]*D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], ϕ] + Sin[θ]*D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], θ, ϕ]/2, 
   Q[t, 0, θ] == Q[t, 2*Pi, θ], Q[t, ϕ, 0] == 0,  
   Q[0, ϕ, θ] == ((1 - Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ])^2 - 1)/4};
sol = NDSolveValue[pde, Q, {t, 0, 5}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, {θ, 0, Pi}, MaxStepSize -> {.01, .25, .25}]
```

generates the message

```
Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 7560.422997509231` at t = 5.` in the direction of independent variable \[Phi] is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 27 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options. >>
```

and exhibits rapid numerically unstable growth.  By `t = 5`, `sol` is as large as `4.23527*10^8`, even though the analytical solution is known to be less than one in absolute value.

The warning message not withstanding, increasing resolution in `ϕ` or `θ` increases the instability growth rate.  I have tried a number of `Method`s, including `"Adams"`, `"BDF"`, `"ExplicitRungeKutta"`, `"ImplicitRungeKutta"`, and `"Extrapolaton"` without substantive improvement.

I would appreciate advice on how to obtain a stable solution.

Note: Although this particular problem is solvable analytically, it is meant as a prototype for more general problems involving `D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], θ, ϕ]` that are not solvable analytically.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to reduce the `PrecisionGoal` by a fair bit.

```
pde = {D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], t] == -Cos[θ]*D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], ϕ] + Sin[θ]*D[Q[t, ϕ, θ], θ, ϕ]/2, 
    Q[t, 0, θ] == Q[t, 2*Pi, θ], Q[t, ϕ, 0] == 0, 
    Q[0, ϕ, θ] == ((1 - Cos[ϕ]*Sin[θ])^2 - 1)/4}; 
sol = NDSolveValue[pde, Q, {t, 0, 5}, {ϕ, 0, 2*Pi}, {θ, 0, Pi}, PrecisionGoal -> 2]
```

Comment: This computation is even more unstable than the one in my question.  Is it possible that one of the `NDSolveValue` parameters was copied incorrectly into the answer?

Comment: @bbgodfrey, I am sorry: What I posted is nonsense. It's a bit late here and I'll have a look tomorrow. The only thing I found so far is to reduce the `PrecisionGoal->2` not ideal which I put in the answer now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to come up with an alternative to reducing the precision goal.

Comment: The solution still is unstable, although growing more slowly to of order `1000`.  It appears that the low `PrecisionGoal` causes `NDSolve` to use a very course mesh, which reduces the numerical instability growth rate.  Thanks for trying, though.